# Confused about the benefit of null safety

Tags: dart

As far as I know, the benefit of null safety is to prevent the accidental assignment of `null` to a variable and then later doing something like `nullable_variable.foo()` which would cause a runtime error.

But even when I am not using null safety, I do get a compilation error when calling a method on an object that have the `null` value, for example I get a compilation error when doing the following:

```
class Student
{
    void foo()
    {
    }
}

void main()
{
    Student? s1 = null;  // not using null safety here
    s1.foo();            // this causes a compilation error
}
```

So what I mean is that I am still getting the benefit of null safety without using null safety, so what is the point of null safety?!

Comment: `Student?` is a nullable type which means it is allowed to be `null` which is also why you get the compile error when trying to call `s1.foo()` since `s1` would potentially be `null`. I don't understand what you mean by enabling and disabling null-safety.

Comment: I don't get it, how are you getting benefit of null safety without it, the above code clearly don't show anything like that. moreover ,it is an example of demerit of not using null safety

Answer (score 1):

You *are* using "Null Safety". The Null Safety feature is what allows you to write `Student?` to begin with, to distinguish between types which allow `null` and types which do not.

With that knowledge, the compiler can disallow calling methods on a nullable type that are not also allowed on `null`. And it does.
You get a compile-time error for something that, without Null Safety, you'd have written `Student s1 = null;`, had that accepted by the compiler, and gotten a runtime error.

The promise of Null Safety is that you get compile-time errors instead of runtime errors. The cost is that you need to check for `null` (or do unsafe casts to non-null types, but checking is better), and you have to explicitly include `null` in types where you do want to accept `null`.

Comment: So in previous versions of Dart that did not have null safety, my code would have been compiled and `s1.foo();` would have produced a runtime error?

Comment: Prior to null safety, you would have written `Student s1 = null;`. You couldn't write `Student?` as a type at all. The old `Student` type was nullable, but unsafely so, because it could throw at runtime if the value is `null`. With null safety, the type `Student` is a non-nullable type and `Student?` is nullable. You can call `Student` methods on the non-nullable type, and not on the nullable type. You have to check first that it is a `Student`, not a `null`.

Answer (score 0):

To say in simple terms using your above example

`Student s1 = null` is valid without null safety which will lead to various other problems , Especially when you are dealing with the huge project.

- So when you opt into `null safety`, types in your code are `non-nullable` by default, meaning that variables can’t contain `null` unless you say they can.
- With null safety, your runtime **null-dereference errors** turn into **edit-time analysis errors.**

Where as in null safety , you can't have somethin like `Student s1 = null`,
Instead use `Student? s1 = null`. Meaning you are explicity saying the compiler that you are aware that this value can be null and take care of it in the entire program.

So flutter accepts that and helps you through by giving features like `!` `??` `?`.

To summarize , the null safety was introduced because,
Developers like statically-typed languages like Dart because they enable the type checker to find mistakes in code at compile time, usually right in the IDE. The sooner you find a bug, the sooner you can fix it. When language designers talk about **“fixing null reference errors”**, they mean enriching the static type checker so that the language can detect mistakes

And Dart is designed to run on an end-user’s device. If a server application fails, you can often restart it before anyone notices. But when a Flutter app crashes on a user’s phone, they are not happy. When your users aren’t happy, you aren’t happy.

Please follow the below links to dive deep into the null-safety concept.

- https://dart.dev/null-safety
- https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety